# Dagger2 ViewModel cannot be provided problem with @Binds ViewModelProvider factory

Tags: viewmodel, dagger-2, dagger

I have implemented the support for injection of ViewModels in complaience with 
[medium article](https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/android-viewmodel-and-factoryprovider-good-way-to-manage-it-with-dagger-2-d9e20a07084c!)
and [googleRepo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/88747993139224a4bb6dbe985adf652d557de621/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github!)

unfortunately i get the error `cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.` and i cant get to the bottom of it.

I have migrated the project to AndroidX. I have tried many answers available on StackOverflow without success.

## AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [
            AndroidInjectionModule::class,
            AppModule::class,
            MainActivityModule::class,
            LoginActivityModule::class,
            DispatcherActivityModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(androidApplication: BeeApp)
}
```

## AppModule

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class AppModule {
...(i provide non-related other object here)
}
```

## ViewModelModule

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(UserProfileViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindUserViewModel(userProfileViewModel: UserProfileViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

## DaggerViewModelFactory

```
@Singleton
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class DaggerViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModelsMap: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) :
        ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = viewModelsMap[modelClass] ?: viewModelsMap.asIterable().firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        return try {
            creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

}
```

## Fragment

```
class UserProfileFragment : BaseFragment(), Injectable {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    lateinit var profileViewModel: UserProfileViewModel

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        profileViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(UserProfileViewModel::class.java)
    }

(...)
}
```

## ViewModel

```
class UserProfileViewModel @Inject constructor(userAccountRepository: UserAccountRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val userAccount: LiveData<Resource<UserAccount>> = userAccountRepository.loadUserAccount(true)

}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an issue with Kotlin kapt on version 1.3.30 [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30979)

change to previous/newer version